# Passing an array of structures from Visual Basic 5.0 to a Visual C 5.0-written dll

Tags: dll

I want to pass an array of structures from Visual Basic 5.0 to a 32-bit Visual C 5.0-written dll, survey32.dll.  On the dll-side, all of the elements of all of the records are garbage which shortly causes an APCRASH.  Clearly the problem is trying to pass an array of structures to the dll. I do not know what thing(s) I am doing wrong as I have repeatedly checked the syntax of declarations, definitions, and function calls and their parameters.

The following are the particulars.  Various other structure members (all either type long or double) and functions local to the dll have been omitted for brevity:

IN VISUAL BASIC:

```
'******************  survey32.dll Exportable Subroutine:  *******************  
                                  'declaration of the subroutine to pass  
                                  'the entire array of structure records  
                                  'as a procedure argument by reference  
Public Declare Sub GetPolygon Lib "survey32.dll" Alias "_GetPolygon@8" _  
   (ByRef survey_data() As SURVEY_REC, ByRef survey_summary As SURVEY_SUM)  


'***************************  General Constants  ****************************  
Public Const NUMELEM = 10          'maximum number of sides in the polygon  


'***************************  Record Structures  ****************************  
Public Type SURVEY_REC             'global survey data record structure  
    bearing_deg As Long            'bearing (degrees)  
    bearing_min As Long            'bearing (minutes)  
    bearing_sec As Long            'bearing (seconds)  
    meridian As Long               'meridian reference line, N (decimal 78)  
                                   'or S (decimal 83)  
    deviation As Long              'deviation from meridian reference line,  
                                   'E (decimal 69) or W (decimal 87)  
    course_length As Double        'length of course, ft  
    x As Double                    'adjusted coordinate pair (x,y) of  
    y As Double                    'station  
    End Type  

Public Type SURVEY_SUM            'global survey summary structure  
    num_elements As Long          'number of traverse data points  
    total_length As Double        'total perimeter length, ft  
    total_area As Double          'total polygon area, sq-ft  
End Type  


'**************************  Array Declarations  ****************************  
Public survey_data(NUMELEM) As SURVEY_REC 'array of survey data structure records  
Public survey_summary As SURVEY_SUM   'the survey summary structure
```

From the VB Watch window these are the values stored in the various members for each record that are passed to the dll:

```
survey_data(0)  
    bearing_deg : 47 : Long  
    bearing_min : 16 : Long  
    bearing_sec : 19 : Long  
    course_length : 65.06 : Double  
    bearing_DecDeg : 0 : double  
    bearing_Radians : 0 : double  
    deviation : 87 : Long  
    meridian : 78 : Long  
    x : 0 : Double  
   y : 0 : Double  

survey_data(1)  
    bearing_deg : 3 : Long  
    bearing_min : 12 : Long  
    bearing_sec : 57 : Long  
    course_length : 49.54 : Double  
    bearing_DecDeg : 0 : double  
    bearing_Radians : 0 : double  
    deviation : 69 : Long  
    meridian : 78 : Long  
    x : 0 : Double  
    y : 0 : Double  

survey_data(2)  
    bearing_deg : 76 : Long  
    bearing_min : 39 : Long  
    bearing_sec : 59 : Long  
    course_length : 147.51 : Double  
    bearing_DecDeg : 0 : double  
    bearing_Radians : 0 : double  
    deviation : 69 : Long  
    meridian : 78 : Long  
    x : 0 : Double  
    y : 0 : Double  

survey_data(3)  
    bearing_deg : 20 : Long  
    bearing_min : 32 : Long  
    bearing_sec : 51 : Long  
    course_length : 63.2 : Double  
    bearing_DecDeg : 0 : double  
    bearing_Radians : 0 : double  
    deviation : 69 : Long  
    meridian : 83 : Long  
    x : 0 : Double  
    y : 0 : Double  

survey_data(4)  
    bearing_deg : 60 : Long  
    bearing_min : 20 : Long  
    bearing_sec : 23 : Long  
    course_length : 139.04 : Double  
    bearing_DecDeg : 0 : double  
    bearing_Radians : 0 : double  
    deviation : 87 : Long  
    meridian : 83 : Long  
    x : 0 : Double  
    y : 0 : Double  


survey_summary  
    num_elements : 5 : Long  
    total_length : 0 : Double  
    total_area : 0 : Double
```

This is the Visual Basic Call to the dll:

```
GetPolygon survey_data(), survey_summary
```

From inside the VB dev environment, one gets a VB error of, "Run-time error '53': File not found: survey32.dll".

IN VISUAL C these are the particulars for the dll:

```
/******   CONSTANTS   ******/  
#define NUMELEM        (10)       //number of expected survey points  


/******   GLOBAL VARIABLES   ******/  
                                  //define the global survey data  
struct SURVEY_REC {               //record structure  
              long bearing_deg;   //bearing (degrees)  
              long bearing_min;   //bearing (minutes)  
              long bearing_sec;   //bearing (seconds)  
              long meridian;      //meridian reference line, N (decimal 78)  
                                  //or S (decimal 83)  
              long deviation;     //deviation from meridian reference,  
                                  //E (decimal 69) or W (decimal 87)  
              double course_length;   //length of course (ft)  
              double x;           //adjusted coordinate pair (x,y) of a  
              double y;           //station  
              };  

struct SURVEY_SUM {                   //define the global survey summary  
                                      //structure  
              long num_elements;      //number of traverse data points  
              double total_length;    //total course length (ft)  
              double total_area;      //total polygon area (sq-ft)  
              };  


struct SURVEY_REC **survey_data;  //array of pointers to the survey data  
                                  //structure  

struct SURVEY_SUM *survey_summary;   //declare an instance of a pointer  
                                     //to the survey summary structure  


/******   FUNCTION DECLARATIONS   ******/  

//functions global to program and exportable (called outside of the dll):  
extern DllExport VOID __stdcall GetPolygon (struct SURVEY_REC **survey_data,  
                                            struct SURVEY_SUM *survey_summary);  

//functions local to this module, not exportable:  
static VOID   __stdcall CalcTraverseAzimuths (struct SURVEY_REC *survey_data,  
                                              long num_elements);
```

From the VC Watch window these are the values present in the various members for the first record that is passed received by the dll:

```
survey_data[0]  
    bearing_deg : 1179649 : Long  
    bearing_min : 176 : Long  
    bearing_sec : 0 : Long  
    bearing_DecDeg : 1179651.9333333 : double  
    bearing_Radians : 20588.810437266 : double  
    course_length : 9.8813129...e-324 : Double  
    deviation : 1947014728 : Long  
    meridian : 5311368 : Long  
    x : 1.6021618...e-306 : Double  
    y : 1.6911933...e-306 : Double
```

Note: Some of the longs look like addresses (the DecDeg and Radians member values are simply derived from the DMS values).

```
extern DllExport VOID __stdcall GetPolygon(struct SURVEY_REC **survey_data,  
                                           struct SURVEY_SUM *survey_summary)  
/*===========================================================================  
 *=========================================================================*/  
    {  
    long   num_elements = 0;      //actual number of coordinate pairs  

                                  //get the number of traverse data points  
    num_elements = survey_summary->num_elements;  

    CalcTraverseAzimuths (*survey_data, num_elements);  

        .                         //ellipses for brevity
        .  
        .  

    return;  
    }  


static VOID __stdcall CalcTraverseAzimuths (struct SURVEY_REC *survey_data,  
                                            long num_elements)  
/*===========================================================================  
 *=========================================================================*/  
    {  
    register int i;  
    long meridian;  
    long deviation;  

    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)  
        {  

//ON SECOND PASS THROUGH THE LOOP, GET A GPF ON NEXT EXECUTABLE LINE....  
//   "Unhandled exception in survey.exe (SURVEY32.DLL):  
//    0xC0000005: Access Violation."  

        meridian = survey_data[i].meridian;  
        deviation = survey_data[i].deviation;  
                                  //convert bearing to decimal degrees  
                                  //and radians  
        survey_data[i].bearing_Radians =   
        DMS2Radians (survey_data[i].bearing_deg,  
                     survey_data[i].bearing_min,  
                     survey_data[i].bearing_sec,  
                     &survey_data[i].bearing_DecDeg);  

        if ((meridian == 78) &&   //trig quadrant I - 'E' of 'N'  
            (deviation == 69))  
            {  
            survey_data[i].azimuth_DecDeg = survey_data[i].bearing_DecDeg;  
            survey_data[i].azimuth_Radians = survey_data[i].bearing_Radians;  
            survey_data[i].back_az_DecDeg = survey_data[i].azimuth_DecDeg  
                                          + 180.0;  
           survey_data[i].back_az_Radians = survey_data[i].azimuth_Radians  
                                           + (double)PI;  
            }  
        else if ((meridian == 78) &&   //quadrant II - 'W' of 'N'  
                 (deviation == 87))  
            {  
                .  
                .  
                .  
            }  

            .  
            .  
            .  
        }                         //end for loop  

return;  
}
```

From inside the VC dev environment, within CalcTraverseAzimuths (), one gets a VC error of, "Unhandled exception in survey.exe (SURVEY32.DLL): 0xC0000005: Access Violation."

I would be most grateful for help and possibly so in simple terms as I am clearly at a loss of my error(s).

Comment: I'm inclined to say that your dll isn't registered, nor is it in any of the commonly-used paths.  At least, that's what `File not found: survey32.dll` says to me.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I apologize.  The dll is present in the same directory as the executable.  This Visual Basic error commonly occurs when something is amiss in the netherworld between the call and the dll's entry point.  The call is successful to the extent that the dll code executes.  It is only that the array of structures is trash.  I remain convinced that I have erred in some declaration, definition, etc. syntax.